# Strange search results with tag synonyms

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, search

If I search for [-[google*] [google-*] is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bgoogle*%5D+%5Bgoogle-*%5D+is%3Aquestion), I would expect 0 results, as the excluded `[google*]` is more general than `[google-*]`. Yet all (and only) [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables) questions show up.

My guess is that this is related to synonyms - presumably the above questions were tagged with [fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/fusion-tables), which was then made a synonym of [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables), and, for some reason this is confusing the search.

Now the above search is just an artificial example to show the results - this could be a problem for practical examples.

Comment: I don't know what's causing this, but I'm not sure it's related to the synonym. There are a lot of `google-` tags with one or more synonyms.

Comment: It looks like the asterisk search is just not catching all the possible tags. For example, [tag:google-places-api] and [tag:google-api-java-client] do not show up for either of them. The list of Google tags is much larger than what's being included in your search.